# Laravel models, relationships how to make a innjoin query using Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

Controller code (which isn`t working)

```
 $employees = Employee::with('department')->get();
```

**Model:department**

```
class Department extends Model
{
...
/**
 * Defining Relationships.
 */
   public function employee()
   {
    return $this->hasMany('GloboDeals\Employee');
   }
}
```

**Model:employee**

```
class Employee extends Model
{
/**
 * Defining Relationships.
 */
....
 public function department()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('GloboDeals\Department','departments_id','id');
}
```

the external ids have the name of `table_id`.

I search and search and none of the solutions are working so I guess  my code is just blehhh, if anyone could check it out and give me an idea.

Comment: Are you looking for the department of an employee or all employee with a department?

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Do you get an unexpected result? What result do you get? What result did you expect?

Comment: Can you post table structures?

Comment: a employee and his departement but lsince both have the same collum name='name' i tried this
    $employees = Employee::leftJoin('departments', 'employees.id', '=','departments.id' )
            ->select('employees.*', 'departments.name as departments_name')->get();

Comment: https://cld.pt/dl/download/06ff03ae-7de7-41f6-a688-9830a85272a4/globodealsv5.png  for database

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent will assume that each table has a primary key column named id. You may define a $primaryKey property to override this convention. In each of your models add its primary key like so for Department model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'department_id';
```

Eloquent assumes that the foreign key should have a value matching the id (or the custom $primaryKey) column of the parent. In other words, Eloquent will look for the value of the department id column in the department_id column of the employee record. If you would like the relationship to use a value other than id, you may pass a third argument to the belongsTo method specifying your custom key: In your case you are calling department() of your employee model:

```
return $this->belongsTo('GloboDeals\Department', 'departments_id', 'departments_id');
```

This means the Employee model will eager load the department details where the relation departments_id of departments table = departments_id of the employees table.

Comment: all tables are plural of model name, 
departments primary id = id, 
Employes primary id=id, 
Employes external id from department=departments_id

Comment: if that is the case, you need to replace the keys return $this->belongsTo('GloboDeals\Department','id','departments_id'); becuase 'foreign_key' comes first from the other table (departments) and the local key comes last departments_id from table (employees)